# cpanel/whm new email account welcome email

Tags: email, cpanel, whm

I've searched around a bit, but can't find anything close to this:

Any script or module out there for sending new EMAIL accounts created in cpanel a "welcome" email?

I can find info on customizing the welcome email when you create a new cpanel account (the one with all the account details), but not when creating new email accounts within cpanel.

Example: we create a new email account "bob@domain.com" and when bob logs into this account for the 1st time there is an email in his inbox saying "Welcome Bob, heres some useful info..." or something like that.

I've read the cpanel API might be able to handle this, but I have no experience with it. I found this module from 2007 that looks close:
https://devkardia.com/software/whm-cpanel-email-user-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

WHM don't have such option to fulfill your requirement but yes there are some api given to do so. The one you mentioned is Joomla plugin, there are some third party billing automation software available (such as WHMCS & Hostbill) which has that ability to do what you looking at.

Here is the API given by WHM and can be implement if you would like to try it out yourself
https://documentation.cpanel.net/dosearchsite.action?queryString=Function+Hooks